# Find text between two regex

Tags: python, regex, text, python-3.x

I'm working on a project where I need to put `git log –p` information from a GitHub project into a database. First I've put the `git log –p` into a *.txt* file and I'm using Python to scan it. (Python is kinda new for me).

The structure of a `git log –p` looks like this:

```
commit 5f0883381054b796b643dcff974435633eed8a79
Merge: 4e1d5f7 8ffg9do
Author: name <email>
Date:   date of commit

    "comment of the commit"

diff --…
index …
--- …
+++ …
@@ …
-…
+…
 …

diff --…
index …
--- …
+++ …
@@ …

commit 737044517f403c1080886a674845fad9c42d6bc0
Author: name <email>
Date:   date of commit

   completion: …

   Signed-off-by: name <email>
   Signed-off-by: name <email>

commit 6bf931a54fd66826f28d2808b7ad822024764d41
Merge: 727a46b 3646b1a
Author: name <email>
Date:   date of commit

   Merge branch …

   * …:
     completion: …
     completion: …
     completion: …

commit c3c327deeaf018e727a27f5ae88e140ff7a48595
Author: name <email>
Date:   date
```

At the moment, I easily get commit, merge, author, date lines with regex.

```
    for line in source:

        commit = re.findall('^commit.{41}',line)
        merge = re.findall('^Merge:.*',line)
        author = re.findall('^Author:.*',line)
        date = re.findall('^Date:.*',line)
        signed = re.findall('Signed-off-by:.*', line)
        diffBlock = re.findall("^['diff''index'+-@].*", line) # bad way, I miss few lines


        for commitLine in commit:
            print (commitLine)
            #post into DB

        for mergeLine in merge:
            print (mergeLine)
            #post into DB
        .
        .
        .
```

But the good way to cut the `git log -p` would be to split everytime I find a commit line. THEN work on theses different blocks.
I also need to get comment block and all "diff" blocks from a commit, which are on multi lines.

I've a problem when I want to get the whole text between 2 commits that I want to put into a variable… With regex that would be `^commit.{41}(.*?)^commit.{41}` (I'll have to think about the last commit for the git log, because it won't end by a commit line).
I'll later need the same method for `diffBlock`.

I've tried many things… Like this for example, but it doesn't work properly. It finds few blocs, but not all of them... (it might be a problem of `"\n"`, I dunno)

```
content = open("catchCommitBlock.txt","rt", encoding="ISO-8859-1").read() #testing file
commitBlock = re.compile("^commit.{41}(.*?)^commit.{41}",re.DOTALL|re.M)
i=0
while i < len (commitBlock.findall(content)):
    print (commitBlock.findall(content)[i])
    i+=1
```

Do you have any idea how I can pass this problem?

P.S. if I’m not clear on something, tell me ^^

Comment: It works indeed.
2 problem though :
- spliting hide the string used for spliting
- it's getting harder to get a line because there is one character per lines now :/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a (uni)diff parser library for Python? Such as [this](https://github.com/matiasb/python-unidiff).